# php table not updating after ajax call

Tags: php

In the network tab I can see my call loads addtoclicks.php?clicks=2&quid=15
The success alert is triggered

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'addtoclicks.php?clicks=' + clicks + '&qid=' + quid,
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
      alert("test");
     },
```

It then try and add one to the clicks total but this isn't working. Have I missed something in my ajax call ?

```
<?php
$quiz = $_GET['qid'];
$clicks = $_GET['clicks'];
$clicks++;
$get = $db->prepare("Update Quiz SET Clicks = :quizplayed WHERE Id = :quiz");
$get->bindParam(':quiz', $quiz);
$get->bindParam(':quizplayed', $clicks);
$get->execute();
```

?>

Comment: whats the value of `var_dump($_GET['clicks']);`? Try casting it with `(int)` so; `$clicks = (int)$_GET['clicks'];`

Comment: Where's your database connection code for `$db` in *that* PHP page?

Comment: What is the actual response from the server?  Have you turned on error reporting?  Checked the PHP error logs?  Checked for errors from the DB query?

Comment: change the type to GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: 
 
Change:

```
$quiz = $_GET['qid'];
$clicks = $_GET['clicks'];
```

to:

```
$quiz = $_POST['qid'];
$clicks = $_POST['clicks'];
```

Option 2: 
 
Change:

```
type: 'post',
```

to:

```
type: 'get',
```

If there is still problem with option 1 change:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'addtoclicks.php?clicks=' + clicks + '&qid=' + quid,
 type: 'post',
 success: function(output) {
  alert("test");
 },
```

to:

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'addtoclicks.php', {clicks: clicks, qid: quid},
 type: 'post',
 success: function(output) {
  alert("test");
 },
```